# Xcode 4.5 building iOS5 app for iOS6 device

Tags: xcode, ios6, testflight

Am I being dense here?  I have an app built in Xcode 4.5 that was targeted at iOS5, which built and deployed over TestFlight just fine.

Today, 2 of my team got their iPhone 5 and now I am trying to get the app on their device.  I changed the target for the project to iOS6, provisioned their devices, and made an archive.  But every time I try to push it through TestFlight I get a "dSYM not found" error.

Do I need to make a whole new provisioning profile for these iOS6 devices, or should this work and there is some other issue I am not seeing?

Have cleaned, removed derived data, etc.  But so far, nothing has worked.

Comment: Not sure but iOS6 demands changes in your code built for previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to re provision the devices and update the profile in XCode or via the "Builds -> Permission Updated Provisioning Profile" option / Button

I have found that After adding a new device i then will download the new profile delete the oldone in xcode then install the new one it's a pain but it works I'm assuming that you already know it has to be an Add Hoc Profile and the device ID's need to be attached to it.